# LoadRunner 12.60 - How can I do gzip compression on raw text and save it into another variable/ parameter?

Tags: c, performance, zlib, loadrunner

Looking for some help with compression around LoadRunner requests.

Our application from one system sends a JSON payload to the server. This JSON Payload has several key-value pairs in raw text (readable format). One of the KV pairs however is not.. The value is in gzip format .

So Payload in UTF-8 text is gzip compressed and then encoded in base64 before the application sends it out.

How can I do this with LoadRunner?
Any help would be greatly appreciated

I tried using zlib library but wasn't very successful.

Adding "ContentEncoding=gzip" in web_custom_request is also changing the payload to Binary body only (x\x9C\xED\x9Ako\x9BH\x14\x86\xFF\x8A.....) that I am not able to change into gzip further.

These are the input and output strings that I am looking the conversion for.

Input: 
Output: H4sIAAAAAAAACrOxr8jNUShLLSrOzM+zjVEy1DOIUVJIzUvOT8nMSwcKhIa46VrEKNnbAQDz7k2YKgAAAA==

https://www.zickty.com/texttogzip/ provides the same conversion which I am trying to mimic.

Comment: The binary data you are showing is a zlib stream, not a gzip stream.

Comment: yes @Mark, that's my problem. I am not able to get it converted to the gzip format.

Comment: Then you need to put that information in your question. Also when you say "I tried using zlib", you need to provide what you tried, with source code.

Comment: Just made changes to the question. Hope it's clearer now. I am looking for a C code that can help with this. Also, when I said I tried using zlib, I meant I keep getting stuck with the code and could not understand a lot of what was mentioned in zpipe.c

Comment: zlib can write gzip streams. You need to read the documentation in zlib.h, and yes, understand the zpipe.c example. After having done that and having genuinely tried to write code to do what you want, and it didn't work, _then_ come back here with _the code_ you tried, what happened, and what you expected or hoped for.

Comment: see built in loadrunner functions lr_zip, and lr_unzip for C, lr.zip & lr.unzip in alternate nlanguages

Comment: @MarkAdler  - thank you for the insights. From what I understand , zpipe.c or zlib.dll - they both basically take whatever data is provided to them, put it into a text file and that text files goes into a gz file. If I unzip the gz file, I see a text file and that has the text in plain text format. 

This is the source of my information : https://isolate.menlosecurity.com/http://sub-second.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-send-compressed-xml-messages.html?m=1

This is not what I am looking for. I am looking for the text itself to be compressed in a gzip compressed string.

Comment: My apologies if I am still not doing it correctly. I don't have the skills of a C developer.

Comment: @JamesPulley - thank you. lr_zip is doing the text compression alright, but it’s coming along with binary headers. And since my requirement is gzip compression and then base64 encoding, it’s not happening as it should.

Comment: Then take the output of the GZIP and put it through a BASE64 Encode function, such as 

https://ptfrontline.wordpress.com/2009/09/30/base64-encodedecode-for-loadrunner/

Comment: Or, a more elegant path

https://www.northwaysolutions.com/loadrunner-vugen-encoding-and-decoding-base64/

Comment: Thanks again @JamesPulley. The last link was very helpful - I feel closer to the solution. Think the only issue that I have now is working on the intermediary message. 

Let's say 
My source string is "ABCDE".
I am running lr_zip first to get an intermediary string that I can consequently run base64 utility on . 

The intermediary message is not readable in Loadrunner and is not being passed correctly for following calls. 

Decoded message is:
 ABCDE 
Intermediate message is:
 ‹ 
Encoded message is:
 H4sI

Comment: Piece of the code that I tried.
sourceMessage="demande.demandeur:123456789";
lr_save_string("ABCDE", "param1");
lr_message( "Decoded message is:\n %s ",lr_eval_string("{param1}"));
lr_zip( "source=param1", "target=intermediateMessage");
lr_message( "Intermediate message is:\n %s ",lr_eval_string("{intermediateMessage}"));
encodedMessage= util_base64encode(lr_eval_string("{intermediateMessage}"));
lr_message( "Encoded message is:\n %s ",encodedMessage);

Answer (score 0):

See LoadRunner documentation on data format extensions to decode and encode on the fly.

Comment: Thanks James! I did look at the documentation. My understanding is that DFEs work on scripts when they are recorded.. this is a custom request that we are making. I have a custom XML payload that I need to compress and do base64 encoding on before sending it out.

Comment: Works bidirectionally, as data comes in for decode and data going out for encode.   This is not just to make it easy for recording